# Uniqueness of minimizer of Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have recently started calculus of variations and face the following task:

> Consider the Lagrangian $$L(y',y):=|y'|$$ on the space of curves $$U = \{y\in C^2([0;T];\mathbb R): y(0)=a, y(T=1)=b \}$$ For which values of $a$ and $b$ does the functional $$A=\int_0^TL(y',y)dx$$ admit a *unique* minimizer? For which $a$ and $b$ does it admit *infinitely many* minimizers?

I tried to use Euler-Lagrange equation, but it gave nothing ($0=0$). Also $L(y',y)=|y'|$ is not strictly convex, so the unique theorem can't be applied.

Then I tried to calculate the integral directly

$$\int_0^T|y'|=\dfrac{y|y|}{2}\bigg|_0^T=\dfrac{y(T)|y(T)|}{2}-\dfrac{y(0)|y(0)|}{2}=\dfrac{b|b|-a|a|}{2}$$

so it doesn't really depend on curve, but only on endpoints,
 so I should have infinitely many minimizers for any $a,b$, but it doesn't really corresponds with question.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Your computation of the integral looks suspicious. Test it with $y(t)=t$, which belongs to $U$ with $a=0, b=T$. The correct result is $\int_0^T |y'|dt=T$. Your method gives $\tfrac{T^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake because of lack of attention. I integrated $|y|$ instead of $|y'|$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that, in general, there are an infinite number of minimizes for  $U = \{y\in C^2([0;T];\mathbb R): y(0)=a, y(T=1)=b \},  $ $\int_0^T |y'|$ . These correspond to the smooth, monotonic functions over $[0,T]$ with $y(0)=a, y(T) = b$. The value taken by the integral at the minimizer is $|a-b|$.

However, you obtain a unique minimizer when $a=b$, the constant function $y(x)=a$. The value taken by the integral of the minimizer is 0. If you take a non-constant $y$, when $a=b$, there will certainly be a point at which $y'$ changes sign. This will "mess" with the integral $\int_0^T |y'|$, and have its result be greater than 0. So the solution is to set $a=b$ and have the constant function as the only minimizer.

Comment: Thank you. I was going in the right direction, but had some problems. Can you explain, please, why do we need condition on monotonicity in the case $a\ne b$? In my opinion, it would be required, if we didn't have the absolute value of $|y'|$ under the integral.

Comment: Your integral was wrong.You have to start with the [definition](https://i.imgur.com/Q2sERrn.png) of the absolute-value function to compute it. You see it's a "nice" function, but only when $y'$ is of constant sign. The  correct way to compute $\int_0^T|y'|$ is to partition $[0,T]$ as a sequence of intervals, such that $sgn(y')$ is constant on each interval. Then do the sum of the integrals over said intervals. To see why this is true, take a simple function with y' negative, and compute the integral.Do the same for pozitive.Don't use the Euler-Lagrange equation, as |x|' is discontinuous.

Comment: This is a good explanation.